# Nuxt2: loadingIndicator based on client URL

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have two different client URLs for the same Nuxt2 app. One of these URLs is just an alias, so there are no differences between the two (same environment variables).

How can I have the `loadingIndicator` property in `nuxt.config.ts` switch between two HTML files based on the client URL? Thanks.